# Azure Automation: PowerShell script to remove suspended Microsoft 365 users from Azure DevOps organization

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, automation, azure-active-directory

I need to create an automation that stays constantly synchronized with the list of users with "suspended" status, those who had their access blocked in Microsoft 365, and removes them from the Azure DevOps organization, both current and future users marked as suspended in 365.

Currently, I'm attempting to achieve this through an automation account in the Azure Portal, using PowerShell 5.1. I'm open to alternative suggestions for implementing this project that don't necessarily need to use an automation account.

At the moment, the runbook runs without errors, but nothing happens – in other words, no suspended user from 365 is removed from the Azure DevOps organization. Here is the current code:

```
# Microsoft 365 authentication parameters
$clientId = "ClientID"
$tenantId = "TenantID"
$clientSecret = "ClientSecret"
$scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

# Get an access token
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$tokenBody = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    scope         = $scope
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

try {
    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUrl -Method Post -Body $tokenBody
    $accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
} catch {
    Write-Output "Error obtaining access token: $_"
}

# Get suspended users
$graphUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled eq false"
$graphHeaders = @{Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"}

try {
    $users = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $graphUrl -Headers $graphHeaders
} catch {
    Write-Output "Error obtaining suspended users: $_"
}

# Azure DevOps credentials
$patToken = "patToken"
$devOpsOrg = "DevOpsOrg"

# Loop through suspended users and remove them from Azure DevOps organization
foreach ($user in $users.value) {
    $email = $user.mail

    # Get user identity in Azure DevOps
    $uri = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$devOpsOrg/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1&subjectDescriptor=" + [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("aad:$($user.id)")
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$patToken)))
    $headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

    try {
        $userToRemove = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get
    } catch {
        Write-Output "Error getting user identity in Azure DevOps: $_"
        continue
    }

    if ($userToRemove.Count -eq 1) {
        # Remove the user from Azure DevOps organization
        $uri = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$devOpsOrg/_apis/graph/users/" + $userToRemove[0].Id + "?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

        try {
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Delete
            Write-Output "User $email removed from Azure DevOps organization."
        } catch {
            Write-Output "Error removing user from Azure DevOps organization: $_"
        }
    }
}

# List all users in Azure DevOps organization
$uri = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$devOpsOrg/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$patToken)))
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

try {
    $allUsers = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get
    Write-Output "All users in Azure DevOps organization:"
    $allUsers.value | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output ("Name: " + $_.displayName)
        Write-Output ("User: " + $_.principalName)
    }
} catch {
    Write-Output "Error getting all users in Azure DevOps: $_"
}
```

Comment: How are you verifying the change to the user? (Note that the API disables the user but doesn't remove the user. The API description is "Disables a user. The user will still be visible, but membership checks for the user will return false.")

Comment: Agree with @JonathanDodds. I tested [Users - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) and found the user is still in the user list when I checked the DevOps user list page.  When I use [Users - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP), I can see the user is not in the list. When the user tried to access the org, he can't access the org.

Comment: You can also use the Users - List to check the result.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, guys. After running the runbook, I verify the changes to the users in the Azure DevOps organization by manually checking the user list on the Azure DevOps page, just as a regular user would do. 
Do you know of any way to effectively remove users who have been dismissed from the company from the user list of the DevOps organization so that they truly disappear from the list, projects and everything?

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT, I edited the code to return outputs and implemented a listing of users present in the Azure DevOps org through the [Users - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) after running the runbook.
But Microsoft 365 suspended users still appear in the DevOps org user list output after running the runbook.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a user in Azure DevOps, we can use [User Entitlements - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1). You can find the `userId` from the [User Entitlements - Search User Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user-entitlements/search-user-entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

Here is my test script:

```
# Define parameters
$organization = ""
$PAT=""
$userId=""

# Define headers
$PATGetBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")
$Authentication = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($PATGetBytes)
$Headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $Authentication) }

#Get user list
$url1= "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Method GET -Headers $headers
$response1| ConvertTo-Json

#Delete user
$url2 = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/userentitlements/"+$userId+"?api-version=7.1-preview.3"
# Send the DELETE request
$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -Headers $headers
$response2| ConvertTo-Json
```